# Build error with new UE5.1 project in Rider

Tags: c++, rider, unreal-engine5

I am just getting started with C++ in UE5.1. I am using Rider 2022.3.1

Upon trying to build the project in Rider, I get the following error:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3073: The command "D:\UE_5.1\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat R2NAlaskaEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\..........R2NAlaska.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6. [C:\Users.....\R2NAlaska\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\R2NAlaska.vcxproj]`

I've tried nuking the intermediate and VS folders and rebuilding the solution with no effect.

Here is the full build log:

```
Build started 1/28/2023 9:09:02 AM.
Logging verbosity is set to: Normal.Project "C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.sln" on node 1 (Games\R2NAlaska target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Development Editor|Win64".
ValidateProjects:
  The project "UE5" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Development Editor|Win64".
Project "C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\R2NAlaska.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  D:\UE_5.1\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat R2NAlaskaEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild
  Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" R2NAlaskaEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild
  Log file: C:\Users\javor\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
  Unable to build while Live Coding is active. Exit the editor and game, or press Ctrl+Alt+F11 if iterating on code in the editor or game
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3073: The command "D:\UE_5.1\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat R2NAlaskaEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6. [C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\R2NAlaska.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\R2NAlaska.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.sln" (Games\R2NAlaska target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.sln" (Games\R2NAlaska target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\R2NAlaska.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
(Build target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3073: The command "D:\UE_5.1\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat R2NAlaskaEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\R2NAlaska.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6. [C:\Users\javor\Desktop\R2NAlaska\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\R2NAlaska.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Note that is warns about Live Coding and exiting the engine, but the engine was not running during these builds.